# Is there difference in notion of measurability in classical versus constructive?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, measure-theory, model-theory, constructive-mathematics

Are there notions of measure and examples of sets measurable in that measure in classical logic but not in constructive logic (I think there cannot be counterexamples in other direction)? Are there differences in notion of measurability in each system?

Comment: I don't know much about constructive mathematics, but I don't think this question even makes sense. If we have some two models of set theory (for some definition of "model"), one governed by classical logic, one by constructive logic, we can't really compare sets contained in one to sets contained in the other. This same issue comes up in in purely classical setting too though - it doesn't make sense to compare sets between models of ZF and ZFC (say).

Comment: @Wojowu There are things one can prove classically but constructively. This does not require a constructivist to accept propositions that are classically wrong (such as all functions being continuous). Then the things one can prove constructively are a subset of what one can prove classically, and the measurability of some set can well be such a thing.

Comment: I think that @Wojowu's point was not about the proveability of a certain fixed proposition, but about the fact that even the sets of which we're trying to assert measureability might be different in the two cases—that is, that the very notion of "subset of $\mathbb R$" might differ depending on the logic.  (I don't know if this is true when we change logic, but it's certainly true when we change axioms, as the fact that there are models of ZF with all subsets of $\mathbb R$ measureable shows—they're different sets, not just different statements about the same sets!)